# android.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

Tags: android

I'm not unsure of why I'm getting this error. Here's the menu in question:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.myapp.MainActivity" >

  <item
  android:id="@+id/action_search"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
  android:title="@string/action_search"
  android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
  android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />


<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Here's the searchable configuration as per the [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

Added to my manifest file:

```
<meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
```

I also have an intent handler in the new search activity. Why is this error showing up? My min sdk is 11.

**EDIT**

In onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
// Associate searchable config with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = 
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = 
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        return true;
```

Comment: post your logcat and also manifest file...

Comment: This could be just an incorrect import, as there are two classes with that name. Are you doing something like `SearchView searchView = (SearchView)menuItem.getActionView();`?

Comment: Yes @matiash, posted above. Stacktry, I'll post those in a minute.

Comment: @settheline Ok, then it's probably just the import. Check that you import `android.widget.SearchView` and not `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` in the Java file where you have this code.

Comment: Sure enough, that was it. Thank you.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

you should use these imports instead of using the support library imports

```
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener;
```

Just to keep in mind that the minimum SDK is marked as `14`

Comment: This won't work if you actually want to use the support library.

Comment: As @KickingLettuce says, when using the support library, the error is reverse, i.e, `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.widget.SearchView`. In this case, replace the line `import android.widget.SearchView` with `import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`

Comment: `implementation'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'` in build.gradle file. and then `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` in your activity file

Answer (score 46):

In the menu.xml your <item></item> has to be

```
<item
  android:id="@+id/action_search"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
  android:title="@string/action_search"
  android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
  android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

with that change in the last line

Comment: thx for `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` should be accepted answer.

Comment: This is the working answer. Worth to be accepted answer.

Comment: this is the one that i've missed out, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 17):

Find `import android.widget.SearchView;` in your imports and replace it with `import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`

Comment: it's funny because I had import `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;` and I needed import `android.widget.SearchView;`

Comment: May be Vote up my answer :)

Answer (score 6):

For me i have only changed

```
app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```

Insted of

```
app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this:

```
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
```

It worked for me.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

instead of using androids

```
android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```

you have to use the apps

```
app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```

as per the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for those using androidx

add this to build.gradle.

```
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
```

then add this

```
 app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
```

and import this in the ManiActivity.kt

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, In the *onCreateOptionsMenu* use

```
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
```

**ie**:use the menu item directly to call `getActionView()` method

instead of

```
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
```

or

```
searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
```

becouse both are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

you can fixed this issue by doing this job in your code

adding this

**import android.widget.SearchView;**

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your build.gradle file

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```

and then add this

```
android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
```

instead of

```
// remove or replace this line 
import android.widget.SearchView;
```

in your activity file

Answer (score 0):

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"/>
```

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
```

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)
        val search = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search)
        val searchView = search.actionView as SearchView
        searchView.queryHint = "Search"
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                adapter.filter.filter(newText)
                return true
            }
        })
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```