# androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.widget.SearchView

Tags: android, material-design, searchview, androidx

When I launch my app the following error is thrown:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.app, PID: 5513
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.widget.SearchView
>           at com.example.app.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:169)

I am trying to use a searchview in the app bar.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24522846/6398434) except it is related to Android X instead.

So you just need to change `import android.widget.SearchView;` to:

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
```

Answer (score 11):

```
<item android:id="@+id/search"
      android:title="@string/search_title"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
      app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
      app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"/>
```

that last line - you need to tell it that you are using the androidx version of Searchview

Answer (score 2):

just change

```
app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```

to

```
app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

Change your import or change your actionViewclass to android.widget.SearchView.